# Is that possible to add order comment in to order email

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates

Is that possible to add some code into email template so that custom/guest can see order comment in new order email?

Answer (score 4):

If you have the order comment enabled and it is storing in the database properly, it is available in the template as the following macro:

```
{{var order.getEmailCustomerNote():escape|nl2br}}
```

the escape directive causes content to be sanitized so nasties can't come through

the nl2br directive keeps customer formatting (carriage returns) so it doesn't turn into one single annoying paragraph, or worse yet, the infinitely long string.

Comment: I couldn't get `:escape|nl2br` to work. As soon as I add it, I get no output. If I remove it, the text shows as expected (though without the nl2br). Any idea what I could be missing?  The code I am using is for a custom template: 
`{{var data.question:escape|nl2br}}`

Comment: @Justin - Note that this => `order.getEmailCustomerNote()` is a `get()` function that retrieves `EmailCustomerNote`, not a simple variable display => `data.question`. In the first instance the items `:escape|nl2br` are parameters being passed to a function, adding them to the second causes an error that munges the display of the variable.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I just added `nl2br()` in the controller for the email template to get it working. Incase anyone else has the same problem, is there a way to apply `nl2br()` to a variable like `{{var data.myvar}}`?